# Arduino DUE- flash space for user

Tags: flash

I need for my project to save only 32bit in non-volatile storage. 
What is the easiest/cheapest way to do that in Arduino DUE?

ArduinoDUE is Atmel SAM3X8E so according to the attached table (from Atmel DS)

[image: Can I use this NFC SRAM space as non-volatile memory?]

In the chip I have 4KB of NFC SRAM. NFC = Nand Flash Controller, so I have 4KB of internal flash in the internal SRAM?

Thanks,

Comment: You'll probably need to "walk" the value through at least one erase block worth of program flash.  Beware some flash architectures with ECC do not permit overwriting unprogrammed bits in a partially programmed word; which may be several bytes long.  So it's best if you can define the erase value as "unused" and simply search until you find the last unerased value, appending any new values on the end.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's at least one library out there to emulate EEPROM functionality in the DUE using Flash.

https://github.com/sebnil/DueFlashStorage

Comment: ROM is not good for me. I need to be able to READ and WRITE, but the data should survive power loss

Comment: you misunderstand what is meant by EEPROM... it is READ / WRITE